# In for/while ， axios.post send the request with the same body. what the different about axios and $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

When I used axios.post, I met this problem

```
var len =5;
var a ={};
function abc(temp){
  console.log(temp);
  axios.post("/",temp);
}
while(len--){
  a.name = len;
  abc(a);
}
```

when I run this code in console, it will send 5 time request with the same payload.

The cause is `var || let` ?

but when I used `$.ajax`, it works normally.

I wanna an answer, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Axios is an async library which you are running through synchronous code. This is why it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is scope of the variable `a` in the `abc` function call.

```
while(len--) {
   let length = len;
   abc( { name: length } );
}
```

This creates a new variable `length` for every iteration and scope is restricted to that iteration.

The answers to this question JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example explain in detail about why this happens and about scope and closure in JavaScript. The above question is an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: I have tried let a new object ,it works ,but i don't not the reason why in my case, i just change axios  to  $.ajax, it works normally , i don't need let a new object for it